# Does ZeosLib allows remote connection to MSSQL in Android?

Tags: android, sql-server, delphi, delphi-xe6, zeos

I would like to know if ZeosLib is ready to be used with Android FMX for accessing MSSQL remotely, like it does in x32.

If not, Is there any external component pack or built-in solution in Delphi that does?

Comment: I'm not aware of any data access library able to access MSSQL from Android. That is mostly due to the fact that there is no SQLClient available for Android. Perhaps anyone can proof me wrong?

Comment: What for? You should access the data through a webserver.

Comment: This is why REST servers were invented, to add a secure layer around data being accessed over the internet, also because you can't find MSSQL drivers for any and every platform.

Comment: Please see for example: http://codeverge.com/embarcadero.delphi.firemonkey/xe5-android-tsqlconnection-to-m/1055900 - it explains that MSSQL (OLEDB) is a windows-only technology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do is not a clean solution to the problem of a connection to a DataStore from an application running on a mobile device, since as someone correctly stated in comments to your question the correct path would be : passing through a web service .

Anyway what you are asking here is : can I use zeoslib to directly connect my Android App to a SQL Server instance  ?

*No, at least at the moment because zeoslib access the database through the SQL Server native library that is, as far as I know, only available on Microsoft Windows platform.*

You could instead use zeoslib to access an Android Db database(that basically is a Sqlite3 database).

However it is possible to connect to a MSSQL instance from an Android FMX app using this [Delphi FMX JDBC Wrapper](http://www.winsoft.sk/ajdbc.htm) and the JTDS JDBC Driver.

> The library is a wrapper of the JTDS project which is an open source
>   java driver for MSSQL. It provides it’s own interface for the library
>   which you receive the source for once you purchase the library. I have
>   not seen another solution for accessing Microsoft SQL Server on
>   Android with Delphi XE5 Firemonkey at this time.

*If you need to use it through zeoslib, you will have to implement a new protocol for this library directly on the zeoslib source.*